# Customized error page in symfony 2.0 using .html.php template

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony 2.0 version with php template. How to create a customized error page using php template? I have basic knowledge in symfony, kindly help me

Comment: you can read [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html)

Answer (score 2):

**The problem**:  Symfony only created a twig ExceptionController.  This is by design:  you can see here that they chose to only support twig for this component, so don't bother opening a ticket with them:  https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7285

**The solution**: You will have create your own ExceptionController.  The original is located at Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController.  I chose not to extend the original as I wasn't using enough from it to warrant the connection.

Below is the controller I ended up with.  It supports looking for PHP error templates first, and upon failing to find one, it will fail over to using the built-in twig ones.

```
namespace Rate\CommonBundle\Controller;

use Rate\CommonBundle\Entity\AjaxResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * NOTE: when overriding twig exception/error templates in the app space, you MUST CLEAR CACHE AFTER ADDING A NEW ONE
 *
 * This file is specified to be used in parameters.yml
 *
 * For "non debug" environments (production), error templates will be used.  For dev environments, exception
 * templates are used
 */
class ExceptionController
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\DelegatingEngine
     */
    protected $templating;
    /**
     * @var \Twig_Environment
     */
    protected $twig;
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $debug;

    public function __construct($templating, \Twig_Environment $twig, $debug)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->debug = $debug;
    }

    /**
     * Converts an Exception to a Response.
     *
     * @param Request              $request   The request
     * @param FlattenException     $exception A FlattenException instance
     * @param DebugLoggerInterface $logger    A DebugLoggerInterface instance
     * @param string               $_format   The format to use for rendering (html, xml, ...)
     *
     * @return Response
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException When the exception template does not exist
     */
    public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null, $_format = 'html')
    {
        $currentContent = $this->getAndCleanOutputBuffering($request->headers->get('X-Php-Ob-Level', -1));
        $code = $exception->getStatusCode();
        $template = $this->findTemplate($request, $_format, $code, $this->debug);

        if ($template->get('engine') == 'php') {
            $engine =& $this->templating;
        } else {
            $engine =& $this->twig;
        }

        return new Response($engine->render(
            $template,
            array(
                'status_code'    => $code,
                'status_text'    => isset(Response::$statusTexts[$code]) ? Response::$statusTexts[$code] : '',
                'exception'      => $exception,
                'logger'         => $logger,
                'currentContent' => $currentContent,
            )
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param int     $startObLevel
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getAndCleanOutputBuffering($startObLevel)
    {
        if (ob_get_level() <= $startObLevel) {
            return '';
        }

        Response::closeOutputBuffers($startObLevel + 1, true);

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param string  $format
     * @param int     $code       An HTTP response status code
     * @param bool    $debug
     *
     * @return TemplateReference
     */
    protected function findTemplate(Request $request, $format, $code, $debug)
    {
        $name = $debug ? 'exception' : 'error';
        if ($debug && 'html' == $format) {
            $name = 'exception_full';
        }

        // when not in debug, try to find a template for the specific HTTP status code and format
        //if (!$debug) {
            $template = new TemplateReference('RateCommonBundle', 'Exception', $name.$code, $format, 'php');
            if ($this->templating->exists($template)) {
                return $template;
            }
        //}

        // try to find a template for the given format
        $template = new TemplateReference('RateCommonBundle', 'Exception', $name, $format, 'php');
        if ($this->templating->exists($template)) {
            return $template;
        }

        // default to a generic HTML exception
        $request->setRequestFormat('html');
        // Check if we have a custom one
        $template = new TemplateReference('RateCommonBundle', 'Exception', $name, 'html', 'php');
        if ($this->templating->exists($template)) {
            return $template;
        }

        // fallback to built-in twig templates
        return new TemplateReference('TwigBundle', 'Exception', $name, 'html', 'twig');
    }
}
```

**Usage**: This controller, as well as my error pages, exist in a CommonBundle in my app.  You can put them in whatever bundle you want, but you will have to tweak the `ExceptionController::findTemplate` function so it is looking at the right bundle.

Note, the second argument in the constructor of TemplateReference() is the sub folder with Resources/views.  So my error templates are in `Rate\CommonBundle\Resources\views\Exception`

**Symfony DI**: Symfony uses the `twig.controller.exception` service when handling exceptions (see it referenced here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html#config-twig-exception-controller), so that is the one you will have to override in your config.yml

```
twig.controller.exception:
    class: %twig.controller.exception.class%
    arguments: [ "@templating", "@twig", %kernel.debug% ]
```

You can see I'm injecting both the PHP template engine and the twig engine.

You must specify your full class path in parameters as well:

```
twig.controller.exception.class: Rate\CommonBundle\Controller\ExceptionController
```

That should do it.  I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

from the link above:

To override the default error template that's shown to the end-user, create a new template located at app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>An Error Occurred: {{ status_text }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Oops! An Error Occurred</h1>
    <h2>The server returned a "{{ status_code }} {{ status_text }}".</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also customize specific error templates according to the HTTP status code. For instance, create a app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig template to display a special page for 404 (page not found) errors.

**EDIT:**
I think if you want it as a php template, and you have the correct settings in your config

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    templating:
        engines: ['twig', 'php']
```

You should be able to just change the extension to .html.php and it should work. (and replacing the twig content for php content offcourse)

**EDIT:**
Try the below as `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>An Error Occurred: <?php echo $status_text ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Oops! An Error Occurred</h1>
    <h2>The server returned a "<?php echo $status_code ?> <?php echo $status_text ?>".</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Please try it and report .  Thx

Comment: Thank you..Yes i used it and its working in twig template. I need this .html.php template.

Comment: I have changed the above content and file name. But again i am getting default 404 error page. Is there any Exception controller page or Class file available to change? Thank you

Comment: did you get it working ? is my answer correct ? your last comment indicates it is not, yet it is marked correct ? should i look further ?

Comment: For twig template your answer correct but in php template again i am getting default 404 error. Kindly help for it

Comment: you are getting a 404?    you should be changing it to error404.html.php  ?   can you try that ?

Comment: I used error404.html.php its also not working. when i use error404.html.php am getting default error page.

Comment: what do you mean by "default error page"   (the custom one looks the same as a default 404 ?) im starting to get confused :)